# Как из двух файлов сформировать массив

Tags: php

Привет!

Насилую свой мозуг уже не первый месяц, но тщетно...., изучая в интернете информацию о php, для того, чтобы сделать следующее:

У меня есть два файла `callendar.txt` и `dayweak.txt`

Мне нужно сформировать из этих двух файлов массив `$massiv = array();`

В файле `callendar.txt` у меня в каждой строке идет дата (например 23.07.2017 и с каждой новой строки следующая дата).

В файлу `dayweak.txt` у меня в каждой строке идет день недели, а именно в порядке:

первая строка - Sun, вторая строка - Mon и т.д.....

Так вот, первая строка файла `callendar.txt` соответствует первой строке файла `dayweak.txt`.. И так какждый номер строки первого файла соответствует тому же номеру строки другого файла...

Ну, то бишь 23.07.2017 - Sun - воскресенье, 24.07.2017 - Mon - понедельник.......

***ЗАДАЧА...***

Мне нужно, чтобы в массиве `$massiv = array();` данные заполнились след образом:

```
$massiv = array('23.07.2017' => 'Sun', 24.07.2017 => 'Mon' и т.д........);
```

то бишь, чтобы строки из файла `callendar.txt` были id массива, а строки файла `dayweak.txt` были его **соответствующими** значениями....

Я уже много чего почитал в инете о переменных, но у меня так и не получилсь написать этот синтаксис, алгоритм..........

Помогите, пожалуйста, дайте пример, как это должно работать...Я новичок, но стою на месте уже много времени.

Очень хочется уже понять это и двигаться дальше...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения

```
// Читаем каждый файл в отдельный массив 
$callendar = file('callendar.txt');
$dayweak = file('dayweak.txt');

// Получаем новый массив
$arr = array_combine($callendar, $dayweak);

// Смотрим результат
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($arr); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Спасибо, Эдуард!! Вот оно в чем дело... Подобную функцию искал, но не находил...... Вот только он не формирует ли в конце ID или элемента массива лишний пробе?? Как мне показалось....

Comment: @SERB если при чтении файлов в массивах есть пробелы, тогда просто добавьте соответствующие константы в функцию file(). Т.е., оба файла надо считывать так: `$callendar = file('callendar.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);` и `$dayweak = file('dayweak.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);` Их описание можно прочитать в мануале: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!!